# Can the base of an elliptically fibered Calabi-Yau threefold be an Enriques surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-surfaces, calabi-yau

For this question, a Calabi-Yau manifold or variety of dimension $n$ is defined as a non-singular projective variety with trivial canonical bundle and $h^{i,0} = 0$ unless $i = 0$ or $i = n$.

If there are no mistakes in [this argument](https://mathoverflow.net/a/307075/8216), the base of an elliptically fibered Calabi-Yau threefold $\pi:X\to B$ has to be rational if $X$ has a trivial fundamental group, but if the fundamental group is not trivial, the base $B$ might be an Enriques surface.

Is it actually possible for the base to be an Enriques surface? Are there restrictions on the fundamental group of the Calabi-Yau variety in that case?

Comment: Let $\nu:\widetilde{B}\to B$ be an etale, degree-$2$ cover of an Enriques surface $B$ by a K3 surface $\widetilde{B}$.  Denote by $i:\widetilde{B}\to \widetilde{B}$ the associated involution.  Let $(E,0)$ be an elliptic curve with involution $j:(E,0)\to (E,0).$  Let $\widetilde{X}$ be the product $\widetilde{B}\times E$ with the involution $(i,j)$.  Denote the quotient by this involution as $q:\widetilde{X}\to X$.  The projection $\text{pr}_{\widetilde{B}}$ on $\widetilde{X}$ induces a morphism $\pi:X\to B$ such that $\pi\circ q$ equals $\nu\circ \text{pr}_{\widetilde{B}}$.